# Easy numbering a figure of multiple drawings

Tags: automation, corel-draw

I'm looking for a simple way to number seperate drawings within a figure, made in CorelDraw X8. The figure has 12 separate drawings (objects, see image). Or is this only possible manually?

[image]

Comment: Hi SPG, Welcome to GDSE. This question is really not very clear. Please add some extra detail to describe your problem or include an image / illustration so that we can understand your problem and provide help.

Answer (score 0):

- You can just type the numbers and align them with the align pannel.
- Or you can insert a table without borders.
- Or if you originally separated the images using the keyboard to move the images, use the same method to move the numbers.

I would probably put the numbers in a new layer so I can play with the position of the numbers without afecting the drawings.